# Loopback4 filter inside the scope return list still

Tags: filter, pagination, include, where-clause, loopback4

I'm using lb4
I have some problems here, I try to find the list with where conditions inside the scope with pagination.

```
 const teacherWithStudents = await this.teacherRepository.find({limit:10,skip:0,
    include: [{
      relation: "student",
      scope: {
        where: { "name": "some random name here" },
      }
    }]
  })
```

The expected teacher's array is : [] (because I searched a random string in student name which is not in DB)

but I got teachers to array without student like this: [{teacherId:1,teacherName:"Stella"}{teacherId:2,teacherName:"Mery"}]

if I filter student names if no teacher has a student that I filtered I need an empty array but I get only a teacher.

I hope I explained the issue in detail.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as the parent and relation queries should be perceived as two separate queries.

First, the list of teachers based on the parent query are resolved. The IDs of the resolved teachers are then used as a constraint when querying for the list of students.

Both results are then combined together to create the final response.

Comment: This will work but we shouldn't hit Db a couple of times to get a single result. Imagine what if you have a 10k record soo tough isn't it?

instead, we can go with the Raw query until we get this resolved by LB

Answer (score 0):

Loopback uses left join. if  you want to find only teachers where student is not null then you have to use inner join with native query.

Comment: Thanks for spending time in this. I already switched to native query. But I'm wonder lb don't have that option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).